# How to create a running current DateTime in a Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, webforms

I'm very new to ASP.net C#. I managed to search online on how to display the current date inside a C# Label. For some reason the **Page_Load** needs to be implemented as a script in the webform and does not work if implemented in the codebehind. My problem is that the time only changes when the page is refreshed. I need the time to change with the system time as it changes. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code to get the current Date and Time :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="StaffTravelInterface.aspx.cs" Inherits="StaffTravel.StaffTravelInterface" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string Day = dt.Day.ToString();
        string Month = dt.ToString("MMM");

        string Hour = dt.Hour.ToString();
        string Minute = dt.ToString("mm");
        timeNow.Text = Day + " " + Month + "   " + Hour + ":" + Minute;
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <style type="text/css">
            #time
            {
                margin-top:-67px;
                float:right;
            }

            #main
            {
                position:static;
                max-width:100%;
            }

            #head
            {
                width:100%;
            }
        </style>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="head" style="background-image:url('../Pics/Header.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:100px">
            </div>

            <div id="time">
                <asp:Label ID="timeNow" runat="server" Text="" style="color:#fea171; font-family:Arial Black; font-weight:bold; font-size:32px"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;
            </div>

            <div id="bg2">
                <img src="Pics/slide.png" style="width:100%; height:100%" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ofcourse it will change while page load or refresh as it is happening on server. Do you want to show server time or client time??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new Timer control to your form, called Timer1, set interval to 1000 (ms), then double click on the Timer control to edit the code-behind for Timer1_Tick.

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="1000" />
```

It will define the timer.
Then add a trigger.

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
    </Triggers>
```

Then add the following script.

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeNow.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Timer1.Start(); gives me a definition error. It says that "System.Web.UI.Timer" does not contain a definition for start. I can't even add "using System.Web.UI.Timer" in my codebehind as it does not exist. Please help.

Comment: I had to add a "ScriptManager" as well. The problem I'm having now is that the entire page refreshes every 1000ms. Is there any way in which I can only make the label update?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your time only changes when the page is refreshed than used IsPostBack Event

```
<script runat="server">
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         if(!IsPostBack)
          {
           DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
           string Day = dt.Day.ToString();
           string Month = dt.ToString("MMM");

           string Hour = dt.Hour.ToString();
           string Minute = dt.ToString("mm");
           timeNow.Text = Day + " " + Month + "   " + Hour + ":" + Minute;
          }
    }
      </script>
```

Hope its working.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer.

My script :

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string Day = dt.Day.ToString();
        string Month = dt.ToString("MMM");

        string Hour = dt.Hour.ToString();
        string Minute = dt.ToString("mm");
        string Seconds = dt.ToString("ss");
        timeNow.Text = Day + " " + Month + "   " + Hour + ":" + Minute + ":" + Seconds;
    }
</script>
```

My Code :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="head" style="background-image:url('../Pics/Header.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:100px">

        </div>

        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Id="timeNow" runat="server" style="color:#fea171; font-family:Arial Black; font-weight:bold; font-size:32px"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000">
            </asp:Timer>
        </div>

        <div id="bg2">
            <img src="Pics/slide.png" style="width:100%; height:100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```